# Xcode iPhone HOW do I interact with a web page that has alreaded loaded?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview

In viewDidLoad I have

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://webpage_etc"]]];
```

which loads the web page fine, but this web page has a name, password and submit button. 
How do I fill in (with Xcode) the name password and hit the submit button.

Answer (score 2):

Use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` to inject some javascript that manipulates the objects in the page.